What is the maximum number of lines that can be added to a NetSuite Sales Order via SuiteScript
I'm using a Suitelet to create Sales Orders and want to know how many lines I can add to the Sales Order and still save without getting an error. I know that NetSuite has documented limits for CSV (5000), Web Services (5000), and UI (500), but I am interested in SuiteScript here.

I added an answer, but I'm curious: is there a practical use case you need to know this for, or is it an 'academic' question?

Just a client wanting to know what the limits are. We're using a Suitelet to replicate the native SO functionality and it's handling multiple discounts per line and then splitting those lines for Available Qty and Do Not Commit commit options. They're concerned that a 50 line order where every line is split and every line has 3 discounts results in a 400-line order.

I was able to validate by testing that it can add up to at least 800 lines (adding 100 lines in increments and saving each time I added 100 lines). So, the limit is not 500, which gets me what I need to know.

Interesting!  Some of the comments in the documentation appear to indicate that at least some of the "limits" are soft limits - "you'll start to run into performance issues above this number" - rather than hard limits imposed by the system.  Does an 800 line order load ok in the UI in your experience?

For suitelets there are two documented limits that I know of.
The "SuiteScript Governance" limit for suitelets is 1000 points.  To create a single sales order, you would use record.create() (10 points) and Record.save() (20 points).  The sublist operations to add lines do not attract usage points.  So you shouldn't hit this limit, based on your question details.
The other limit is the "Script Execution Time Limit", which for Suitelets is limited to 300 seconds (5 minutes).  How many lines can be added within this timeframe will depend on what features are enabled and any customizations within your account.  I think it unlikely that you would be able to create a sales order with anywhere near 5000 lines within that time limit.
If you have a use case where you need to add so many lines to a sales order that you are running near the time limit, you should consider handing the bulk of the work off to a scheduled script instead, which has a time limit of 3600 seconds (1 hour).
Also, consider performance impacts if you ever need to do anything to the record in the UI. EG: adding a memo, loading it for fulfillment, or creating an invoice could take an impracticably long time.
